# Find the mistake in each of the following sentence

Tags: vocabulary, grammaticality-in-context

Find the mistake in each of the following sentences:

1. Oil is an important tropical material that can be processed into many different products.
2. I am sorry, I cannot see what do you mean.

---

My thoughts :

In first sentence: I am not sure the mistake in “that” and it will be “which” or the mistake in “tropical” and it will be “financial”

In second sentence: i think i will remove “do”

Comment: Is this from a test?

Comment: From assignment

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you think might be wrong? Otherwise, this might be considered as proofreading.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [which vs that in complex sentences](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/26352/)

Comment: I wouldn't call **oil** a **material** whereas it's actually a **substance**. The rest of first sentence is fine to me. In the second sentence "**do**" is definitely wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Which" vs "That" in complex sentences](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/26352/which-vs-that-in-complex-sentences)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct about both sentences.

In the 1st sentence the grammatical mistake (if there is one) is the use of *that* instead of *which*. The use of *tropical* in place of *financial* is a possible *factual* mistake, which a student of English might not be expected to know, but it is not a *grammatical* mistake which a student of English ought to know.

The American blogger in [Writers' Digest](https://www.writersdigest.com/write-better-fiction/which-vs-that) suggests the following test :

> If the sentence doesn’t need the clause that the word in question is connecting, use **which**. If it does, use **that**.

The first clause can stand by itself ("Oil is an important tropical material") without losing or altering the meaning. So according to American English usage we should use *which* here. It should also be preceded by a comma :

> Oil is an important tropical material, **which** can be processed into many different products.

Such a non-essential use is termed **non-restrictive**. However, as Clare implies in a comment, in this sentence it is also possible to interpret the subordinate clause as being essential information which is required to identify **which kind** of the many important tropical materials oil is. Such a **restrictive** interpretation requires the use of **that** in American English.   A slight alteration makes this clearer :

> Oil is **one of the** important tropical materials **that** can be processed into many different products.

In British English the use of **which** (without a preceding comma) in place of **that** is accepted in such **restrictive** cases. See [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://web.archive.org/web/20220825043635/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/that-or-which).

> Oil is an important tropical material **which** can be processed into many different products.

---

In the 2nd sentence the word "do" is not required. "What do you mean?" is a sentence on its own :

> "I'm sorry, I cannot see. What do you mean?"

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the use of *that* in *Oil is an important tropical material that can be processed into many different products*. Either *which* or *that* can be used. If the clause  is nonrestrictive, we use *which* and not *that*, as in *Oil is an important tropical material, which  can be processed into many different products*.

Comment: In addition, the information given by the author of the Writers' Digest blog about using only *that* for restrictive clauses gives his preference; but he is wrong to state his preference as a rule.